# Как при выборе чего то в comboBox совершать действие?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Учу pyqt5. В QtDesigner я добавил виджет comboBox. Там есть три варианта выбора. Фортепиано, классическая гитара, бас-гитара. Как при выборе пользователем к примеру первого варианта мне совершать что-то? Я дошел в документаций до сигналов и слотов, но не понимаю как сделать такое. Буду рад примерчику. Мой код стандартный, просто в qt desinger создал окно, добавил combobox и в него 3 элемента о которых уже говрил.

Comment: Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваш примерчик, который вы уже написали.

Comment: Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваш модуль `.ui`

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать сигналы `QComboBox.currentTextChanged` или `QComboBox.currentIndexChanged`.

В функции инициализации окна подключите к сигналу необходимую функцию.

Пример:

```
class Window():

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
    self.comboBox1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.do_something)
    ...

    def do_something(self, value):
        print("Значение ComboBox изменено", value)
```